# Прошу подсказать как реализовать идею

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы контент который выделил зеленым переключался, так скажем страницы, по нажатию на кнопки которые обвел красным цветом.
Тоесть это одна html страница, на которой все эти элементы, и по клику кнопок они должны листаться.

Прошу подсказать что это, или где найти примеры

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

обычный пейджер или пагинация. Гугли как pager или pagination.

Тебе по клику на кнопку нужно получать номер страницы, отправлять его на сервер. Сервер тебе будет присылать нужную страницу, которую ты и вставляешь в зеленый блок.

можно сделать и обычным ajax и js, не нужно подключать вью или реакт